# IE: navigator.msSaveBlob not working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, export-to-csv

I am trying to export CSV file it works fine on Edge, Chrome, Firefox but on IE 11 it fails.

```
        var objectUrl =someURL;
        if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0) {
            var csvData = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
            var fileName = 'fileName.csv';
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(csvData, fileName);
        }
        else {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.style.display = "none";
            a.href = objectUrl;
            a.download = 'fileName.csv';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        }
```

On IE 11 file gets downloaded but when I try to open it gives below error:

[image]

Comment: your IE code block works fine, can't reproduce

Comment: the IE code attempts to download `new Blob([data]` ... the non-IE code attempts to download whatever `someURL` is ... perhaps `someUrl` is valid, and whatever `data` is, is not

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, Many people have suggested the same approach. data is valid I have checked that one.

Comment: `Many people have suggested the same approach` - what approach? I never suggested an approach. I said your code block for IE11 works AS IS (given dummy `data` of `'a,b,c'` for example), so your problem can not be reproduced

Comment: @JaromandaX I meant on the different blog post. thanks for your time man.

Comment: does downloading at https://jsfiddle.net/w42uedf3/ work?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it does but I am using the same code base. Need to see is it related to permission.